# Using virtualenv with legacy Django projects

Tags: django, virtualenv, pip

I am finally going to start using virtualenv for my Django projects on my development machine. Before I start I want to know if there are any special considerations for dealing with my existing projects. My presumed workflow is something like:

1. make a new virtualenv
2. activate the new virtualenv
3. Install Django in there
4. pip install all the packages I know I need for my existing project
5. copy my Django project files, app files, and git files into the project folder within the virtualenv.

**Edit**
6. make requirements file for deployment

This is obviously very simplified but are there any steps or considerations I am fundamentally missing? Is git going to be happy about moving? Also is it best practice to have a separate virtualenv for each Django project?

I know this is not a typical code problem, but I hope those that know more than I do can point me in the right direction.

Many thanks.

Comment: Never regretted switching to using virtualenv

Comment: Yep, I'm a little ashamed I put it off for so long.

Comment: Also edit wsgi.py and your mod_wsgi files if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see any big issue on migrating your projects and I think your 5-steps plan is correct, in particular, for steps 3/4/5 (I'd merge them), you can handle project dependencies with pip, possibly using [requirement files](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html).

Requirement files are plain text files telling to pip which packages have to be installed in your virtualenv, included your git-tracked projects which eventually can be deployed in your virtual environment as development eggs (they bring with them version control infos).
Once you have a req file, it's a matter of:

```
pip install -r file.req
```

to have all needed packages installed in your env.
As you can see from virtualenv docs, a typical req file would contain something like:

```
django==1.3.0
-e git://git.myproject.org/MyProject.git#egg=MyProject
```

I usually keep each project in its own virtualenv, so I can deploy it to the production server the same way I do for local development.